# Sending a json array with ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to send to php a json array.
I'm pretty sure that the data is being sent but i didn't figure out how to parse it.
As you can see in the following code

javascript:

```
var employees = [
    { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
    { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
    { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName": "Jones" }
    ];

    $.ajax({
        url:an url,
        type:"POST",
        data:employees,
        dataType:"json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert (errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

php:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $data = json_decode($_POST['employees']);
        //how do I access the name in the first item ??
        $data = array('success'=>$data[0].firstName);
    echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: mdsl's answer seems correct - but you could have just read the manual, or run var_dump on the results yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `true` as the second parameter of `json_decode`, you will get an associative array and can access John by `$data[0]['firstName']`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending data as JSON, encode the data as json with JSON.stringify and set the content type to json

```
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(employees),
```

then read the data on the server

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$data = array('success'=>$data[0].firstName);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

`employees` is an array of objects, not JSON. And even though you are accessing `$_POST['employees']`, you never send any data with key "employees" to the server.

If you want to do exactly that, then you have to convert `employees` to JSON and assign it to the key "employees".

```
data: {employees: JSON.stringify(employees)}
```

And in PHP, members of objects are accessed via `->`, not `.`:

```
$data[0]->firstName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                <?php
                    header('Content-Type: application/json');
                $var ='[
                    {
                        "firstName": "John",
                        "lastName": "Doe"
                    },
                    {
                        "firstName": "Anna",
                        "lastName": "Smith"
                    },
                    {
                        "firstName": "Peter",
                        "lastName": "Jones"
                    }
                ]';
                    $data = json_decode($var);
                    echo $data1 = $data[0]->firstName;

                    echo json_encode($data);

                ?>
```

Comment: This is only for fetching single data or as you told  above that you didn't figure out how to parse it  [use this link to check my code live](http://codepad.org/X3jVXz2t)

Comment: The OP's primary problem is how to *send* the data, not how to parse it.